# C MacroMagic - Struct Definition

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Im looking for a solution for define a struct, where the user may enable/disable struct members as in the example (pseudo-code):

```
#define DEF_STRUCT_1(NAME,VAL1,VAL2)      \
    struct my_struct_t                    \
    {                                     \
      #if(NAME == TRUE)                   \
        bool name;                        \
      #endif                              \
      #if(VAL1 == TRUE)                   \
        bool val1;                        \
      #endif                              \
      #if(VAL2 == TRUE)                   \
        bool val2;                        \
      #endif                              \
    } instance1

void main() {
  DEF_STRUCT_1(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE);

  instance1.name = true;
  //instance1.val1 = false; // error, unavailable
  instance1.val2 = false;
}
```

Comment: did you mean to tag `macos` and not `macros`?

Comment: Please define "the user". Is it an end user, or is it a developer adopting your library in their application?

Comment: Based on the source code at the end, it seems you want the availability of a member to depend on what value is in another member while the program is executing. That is not supported by C. The definition of a structure is set at compile time. One way to implement that sort of function in your own code would be to create functions to get or set values for members. Then the function that would set a value for `val1` could check whether `name` were true and either set the value or report an error. That sort of implementation is overkill for most purposes.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this construct?  This *feels like* an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619), and the "solution" you are trying to work out for this unknown problem isn't even really sensible.

Comment: This is definitely an XY problem. There are other much more suitable mechanisms for this than macros: struct forward declaration, function pointer callbacks etc. I would abandon this idea and get back to the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yes, this is correct

Comment: @RuudHelderman Developer adopting the library

Comment: @EricPostpischil not quite. i would like to define the full struct, but the user(developer) using this struct may exclude some members at COMPILE time with macros..

Comment: @Claies i dont understand. the idea is to create a structure like a ferrari. but if a fiat is also doing the job, you may select the fiat and save a lot of ram. the point is, this specific struct is used in EVERY single object. therefore it would be nice to define it once but have it configurable

Comment: @Lundin i think we do not talk about the same ;) let me try again: it is all done at compile time. the structure is not modifiable by the developer (this is the idea). but the developper may shorten it if some members are not used (by configuring it)

Comment: @aphardt What Lundin posted is correct. Conditionally defining `struct` fields in this manner will create a `struct` that is horribly difficult to write code for - you can't use `#ifdef` preprocessor directives to control code compilation, so there's no way to use what you're trying to do to control both code and fields.  Using something like `#ifdef MYSTRUCT_HAS_NAME` can control both at compile time and is much better.  If a developer wants to change the structure definition - **then the developer can change the structure definition**.  It's not hard to add or remove `bool val1;`.

Comment: "The structure is not modifiable by the developer, but the developer may shorten it if some members are not used." I am curious about your use case. Can you explain why it is important that developer can exclude members, but not add members? What makes you think a struct can anticipate on every possible field a user may need? Why not give the developer full control over (a subset of) the struct?

Comment: @aphardt OK, that clears up the issue some. There are some standard (though ugly) ways to do that, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how useful this is, but the following should do what you ask:

```
#define CONDITIONAL_TRUE(code) code
#define CONDITIONAL_FALSE(code)

#define DEF_STRUCT_1(NAME,VAL1,VAL2)      \
    struct my_struct_t                    \
    {                                     \
      CONDITIONAL_##NAME(bool name;)      \
      CONDITIONAL_##VAL1(bool val1;)      \
      CONDITIONAL_##VAL2(bool val2;)      \
    } instance1

int main() {
  DEF_STRUCT_1(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE);

  instance1.name = true;
  //instance1.val1 = false; // error, unavailable
  instance1.val2 = false;
}
```

All the `TRUE`/`FALSE` parameters would have to be available at compile-time. And if you want more than one version of these parameters to be used in the same program, you should make the struct name a parameter as well.

Since you say that this is intended for a library, it isn't clear how you're planning for the library code to be able to access this struct, since it would need to know which members are available. This significantly reduces the usefulness of this method.

A more common method used by libraries is to have a config.h file, editable by the library user, with definitions such as `#define USE_NAME_MEMBER 1`. Then you can make a normal `struct` definition with `#if` directives:

```
//in mylibrary.h:
#include <mylibrary_config.h>

struct my_struct_t {
    #if USE_NAME_MEMBER
        bool name;
    #endif
    /...
};
```

Then you would also put `#if` directives around any library code that accesses the `name` member.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the struct needs to be generated differently at compile-time, given some conditions, you will be facing the problem that all code using the struct will need to be modified accordingly. Compiler switches (`#ifdef FOO .... #endif`) tend to scale badly with increased complexity. If there is a large number of struct members, all the needed compiler switches will make a horrible, unmaintainable mess out of the program.

There is a well-known design pattern known as "X macros", that can be used to centralize maintenance in programs to one single place, as well as allowing compile-time iteration of all items involved. They make the code hard to read too, and therefore they are a bit of a last resort. But they are a bit of de facto standard and their ugliness doesn't scale with complexity, so they are preferred over some compiler switch madness. It goes like this:

```
#define INSTANCE_LIST \
/*  name, type */     \  
  X(name, bool)       \
  X(val1, bool)       \
  X(val2, bool)       \

typedef struct
{
  #define X(name, type) type name;
    INSTANCE_LIST
  #undef X
} instance_t;
```

This code gets pre-processed into:

```
typedef struct
{
  bool name;
  bool val1;
  bool val2;
} instance_t;
```

The only part that needs to be maintained is the "INSTANCE_LIST". By commenting out a line in the list, that struct member will go away. This means that all code using the struct has to be using the same list accordingly. For example, lets add code to the same example, that lists the init values of each member and then sets them:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INSTANCE_LIST       \
/*  name, type, init */     \  
  X(name, bool, true)       \
  X(val1, bool, false)      \
  X(val2, bool, false)      \

typedef struct
{
  #define X(name, type, init) type name;
    INSTANCE_LIST
  #undef X
} instance_t;

int main (void)
{
  instance_t inst;

  #define X(name, type, init) inst.name = init;
    INSTANCE_LIST
  #undef X

  printf("%d ", inst.name);
  printf("%d ", inst.val1);
  printf("%d ", inst.val2);
}
```

Very flexible and maintainable - you can easily add more struct members without changing any other macro than the list. But as mentioned, the down-side is that the code looks quite cryptic, especially to those who aren't used to this design pattern.